# Encrypting Crypt field using Classic ASP for SagePay Form Integration

Tags: forms, asp-classic, aes, encryption-symmetric, opayo

I always get the same error 3045: The Currency field is missing, when posting this form:

```
<form name="frmPay" action="https://test.sagepay.com/gateway/service/vspform-register.vsp" method="POST">
<input type="text" name="VPSProtocol" value="3.00" />
<input type="text" name="TxType" value="PAYMENT" />
<input type="text" name="Vendor" value="myvendor" />    
Crypt:<textarea rows="10" cols="200" name="Crypt"><%=Crypt%></textarea>
<input type="submit" value="Send" />
</form>
```

I think the error is in the encryption

Could someone send encryption routine for classic ASP?

Comment: This [question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/23787701/692942) also complains about the currency field, might be worth a look it is for PHP however but might help track down the problem.

Answer (score 2):

> **UPDATE (19-Nov-2014):** A useful link has come to light through [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26993768/692942) on this topic.
>
> https://www.sagepaylabs.com/AES.zip
>
> The file contains Classic ASP example of how to implement AES (128-bit) using a modified version of the AES Rijndael Block Cipher originally written by Phil Fresle (2001) but has been modified by Mat Peck at Sage Pay to run with 128-bit blocks (AES) with CBC and PKCS#5 padding.
>
> The Classic ASP example contains two files
>
> ```
>   includes.asp
>   rijndael.asp
> ```

---

The Sage Pay Form Integration requirement is very specific.

> **From [Form integration protocol and guidelines](http://www.sagepay.co.uk/file/6941/download-document/FORM_Protocol_and_Integration_Guidelines_300114.pdf?token=SYAK3maL_Ite0jxNhVK2CpjZ9fcAe1O6t7KgnoJGAuk)**
>
> ***A1.1 The Crypt Field***
>
> 1. *The Crypt field should contain all the other transaction information (see the next section) in plain text as Name=Value fields 
>      separated by ‘&’ characters. Ensure that all mandatory fields are present and that there are no spaces after the ‘&’ character.*
> 2. *This string should then be encrypted using AES(block size 128-bit) in CBC mode with PKCS#5 padding using the provided 
>      password as both the key and initialisation vector and encode the result in hex (making sure the letters are in upper case).*
> 3. *Prepend the `@` sign to the beginning of the encoded result.*
>
> ***NB : To decrypt use the same procedure in decryption mode, making sure you remove the `@` sign before doing so.***
>
> ---
>
> ***Example Crypt Field***
>
> *Using the key `55a51621a6648525`
>
>   To encrypt the following request we should get the encrypted result below it*
>
> ***Key Value Pairs***
>
> ```
> VendorTxCode=TxCode-1310917599-223087284&Amount=36.95&Currency=GBP
> &Description=description&CustomerName=FnameSurname
> &CustomerEMail=customer@example.com&BillingSurname=Surname
> &BillingFirstnames=Fname&BillingAddress1=BillAddress Line 1
> &BillingCity=BillCity&BillingPostCode=W1A 1BL
> &BillingCountry=GB&BillingPhone=447933000000&DeliveryFirstnames=Fname
> &DeliverySurname=Surname&DeliveryAddress1=BillAddress Line 1
> &DeliveryCity=BillCity&DeliveryPostCode=W1A 1BL
> &DeliveryCountry=GB&DeliveryPhone=447933000000
> &SuccessURL=https://example.com/success&FailureURL=https://example.co/failure
> ```
>
> ***Encrypted Result***
>
> ```
> @2DCD27338114D4C39A14A855702FBAB2EF40BCAC2D76A3ABC0F660A07E9C1C921C2C755BA9B59C39F882FBF6DFED114F23141D94E50A01A665B1E3
> 1A86C07CA1CD1BB8EF5B6CF2C23D495CD79F9C0F678D61773E7A1AA30AA5B23D56503FC0B52AC0694A8C341263D2C5FE1BAD93BDB94726761E155E9
> 00448F644AF1F67BE1AC77E852B9D90809A44F258EE9478B6D8C1C4ED58759263E7DBF8871C6592287C0358F36F4EEC326CEDDD440DA2FED8AB35F1B
> 630A5C6FA671E4D78CC8CACECF9DFDC31D6C5EC8270FB21E297E2C2E14F99A04223EFFD4F00062D440E78A3D2C7140EC8F123D247B75E7482AE98858
> DA34D37EDE6D7C69AA74391F559305CF675ADB3615244A107ABBB6AF26E29A2FFA059B12688D90FE09E0DE069325BFF3587A695F5DA36E4B809B69C
> C9A37034F166B63B5A62B986F4DA34E9AC9516AFDE70642EC7DAD1AEBA93A1F347D6AC7046E967DCBFE7ACFCEE5DAFC0B29F1765032B3060EBE565C
> BD57D092075D15CF12725199C6881605B2E0F105698CE3ADD04361CA9D620C187B90E3F9849445B5C3C0FDF1768BFFD61F97E51316826F4F10E0E3E6
> 68F0A9F5ED9CCDA6F2C7CC957F12DB48F9041482E3D035E7A91852C404BFA325FED947E71F57B871DFAC6AF4FF29F4513A4A80B2D7ECC9D19D47ED04
> FA99CDFC881DFA771E1EA4F3F9B2C5AC673EF3DA2699A309CC8522993A63CB8D45D3CDF09B1DFDC573CD19679B250AD6721450B5042F201670B4645
> 05DCAEF59E2C67ABACC9AE2EEE793CE191FEBF66B8FAF4204EFFB359246B9C99FB52805C46375FF35140F74707FBC73C7731A28A2C883A
> ```

<strike>Taking into consideration these requirements means your limited on the options available in a Classic ASP environment.</strike>

I would recommend on looking at using [AspEncrypt by Persit Software](http://www.aspencrypt.com/) or the only other promising option I can find is [(Classic ASP) AES Encryption](http://www.example-code.com/asp/crypt2_aes.asp) but as I have not used either of these components I cannot vouch for how good or bad they are.

---

However I have used Persit components before during web development using Classic ASP and can say that they have always worked for me so my recommendation would be to have a look and see what you think.

It does seem to support the needed requirement, here is an example [based on code from the documentation](http://www.aspencrypt.com/manual_02.html) manipulated to suit.

```vb
<%
Dim CM, Context, Key, Blob, Crypt

Set CM = Server.CreateObject("Persits.CryptoManager")
'AES requires the Microsoft Enhanced RSA and AES Cryptographic Provider.
'Set Context = CM.OpenContext("", True )
Set Context = CM.OpenContextEx( _
  "Microsoft Enhanced RSA and AES Cryptographic Provider", "", True _
)
Set Blob = CM.CreateBlob
Blob.Hex = "Hex Encoded Key given to you by Sage Pay" 'AES-128 Bit Key
'Might need to reverse the bytes which is why the third parameter is set to True.
Set Key = Context.ImportRawKey(Blob, calgAES128, True)

'Make sure padding is set to PKCS#5 and Cipher Mode is set to CBC
'these don't actually need defining because they are the defaults
'according to the documentation, just here for completeness.
Key.Padding = ccpPKCS5
Key.Mode = ccmCBC
Set Blob = Key.EncryptText("your key value pairs")

'Format encrypted field as required by Sage Pay
Crypt = "@" + Blob.Hex
%>
```

---

**Useful Links**

- This question appears to be related but is for PHP not Classic ASP the problem though is similar. [PHP and Sage Pay](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23787701/692942).
- [Article PS040625142 - Advanced Encryption Standard (AES) Support](http://support.persits.com/show.asp?code=PS040625142)

Comment: hi Lankymart, thanks for your help, I have this error "Invalid type specified. " in this line Set Key = Context.ImportRawKey(Blob, calgAES128) can you help me?

Comment: @user3889418 Assuming it's `calgAES128` constant value not being identified by the current Cryptographic Service Provider there is a section on them [here](http://aspencrypt.com/manual_02.html#2_5). Because you want to use `AES` you might be limited by what's supported on OS which needs to support the `Microsoft Enhanced RSA and AES Cryptographic Provider` *(Windows Server 2003 or later)*. You might need to change the `Set Context` line to `Set Context = CM.OpenContextEx("Microsoft Enhanced RSA and AES Cryptographic Provider", "", True)`.

Comment: this is correct?
TextToEncrypt = "VendorTxCode=........"
Set CM = Server.CreateObject("Persits.CryptoManager")
Set Context = CM.OpenContextEx("Microsoft Enhanced RSA and AES Cryptographic Provider", "", True )
Set Blob = CM.CreateBlob
Blob.Hex = "55a51621a6648525" 
Set Key =  Context.ImportRawKey(Blob, calgAES128)
 
Key.Padding = ccpPKCS5
Key.Mode = ccmCBC
Set Blob = Key.EncryptText(TextToEncrypt) 
Crypt = "@" + Blob.Hex

I have this error "Invalid flags specified." in the line Set Key =  Context.ImportRawKey(Blob, calgAES128)

Comment: Perhaps this will help? [Article PS01032928 - Invalid algorithm specified / Invalid flags specified](http://support.persits.com/show.asp?code=PS01032928). The code I have provided is pseudo coded from snippets in the documentation to fit the requirement and as such is untested, it will simply be a matter of trying to work through the issues I'm afraid. If your having trouble with the constant values step 3. suggests adding TypeLib reference to your page, personally I would go a stage further and suggest you add it at the top of the `global.asa` file so it is available across the app.

Comment: @user3889418 Also while looking through the support articles notice they are using `Set Key = Context.ImportRawKey(Blob, calgAES128, True)` the third argument sets we are reversing the bytes (the default is False).

Comment: hi Lankymart, I'm still have the error "Invalid type specified. " in this line Set Key = Context.ImportRawKey(Blob, calgAES128, true), It's possible than Persits.CryptoManager don't accept calgAES128?
How can I add the TypeLib reference ?

Comment: @user3889418 Best way to add the type ref `<!--METADATA TYPE="TypeLib" UUID="{B72DF063-28A4-11D3-BF19-009027438003}"-->` is to add it as the first line in your `global.asa` file (this resides in the root of the application ordinarily the website root but not exclusively). That will be the reason for the `Invalid Type Specified` error because it can't find reference for `calgAES128`. To test it try putting the raw value in of `26126` instead of the constant `calgAES128`. If that is the case though it will error at the next constant values like `ccpPKCS5` and `ccmCBC`.

Comment: @user3889418 Here's a good article on adding [METADATA references](http://www.4guysfromrolla.com/webtech/110199-1.shtml).

Comment: @user3889418 How did you get on, did the link help?

Comment: @user3889418 Add you added the Type Ref to your `global.asa` file?

Comment: yes, do you have and vb.net example? now I'm trying in vb.net but I don't have myRijndael.IV what is this?

Comment: @user3889418 Not sure if this is still relevant to you, but another person asked a [similar question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/26993768/692942) and an answer given points to a [useful resource](https://www.sagepaylabs.com/AES.zip) otherwise unknown, it uses a modified version of `rijndael.asp` to support 128-bit, might be worth a look.

Comment: @user3889418 Might to too late now but another question about the same issue was posted which has a [promising answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/28435492/692942) posted by [@Paul](http://stackoverflow.com/users/4551114/paul). Might be worth a look if you are still struggling.