# Sagepay Forms encryption method Classic ASP

Tags: forms, asp-classic, opayo

I have a bespoke shopping cart developed using Classic ASP and I need to integrate it with SagePay Forms.

I am struggling to find any documented ASP code examples of how to encrypt the orders data to send to Sagepay.

Could anybody who has done this point me in the right direction?

Comment: This [SO question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/25025330/692942) may help, posted this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/25026284/692942) a while ago on a similar subject included link to the [Form integration protocol and guidelines](http://www.sagepay.co.uk/file/6941/download-document/FORM_Protocol_and_Integration_Guidelines_300114.pdf).

Comment: I read through that info before posting. The key thing is the previous poster could not get it to work as far as I could see. I am comfortable preparing the data pairs stuff - its the encryption of it I am struggling with

Comment: If you have to use `AES` encryption then you are limited in your options (which I explain in that answer). Try out that component I recommend and have a go with the code example, once you have something post it in your question and I'll try to help from there.

Answer (score 3):

There are some classic ASP examples [here](https://www.sagepaylabs.com/AES.zip).

Comment: +1. And thank you for sharing the info over on http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25025330/encrypting-crypt-field-using-classic-asp-for-sagepay-form-integration :-)